# R T.test for multiple thresholds in a map-function

Tags: r

I want to perform t.tests for multiple thresholds and multiple dataframes.
Here is my example-code with the thresholds 1, 2 and 3:

```
df1 <- tibble(
var1A= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var1B= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var2A= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var2B= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var3A= rnorm(1:10) +3,
var3B= rnorm(1:10) +3)


df2 <- tibble(
var1A= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var1B= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var2A= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var2B= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var3A= rnorm(1:10) +3,
var3B= rnorm(1:10) +3)


df3 <- tibble(
var1A= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var1B= rnorm(1:10) +1,
var2A= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var2B= rnorm(1:10) +2,
var3A= rnorm(1:10) +3,
var3B= rnorm(1:10) +3)
```

No I want to run a t.test for variables A and B for all dataframes.

This code works for the first threshold 1:

```
list_dfs = c('df1','df2','df3')

map(mget(list_dfs),
function(x)
{t.test(x%>%pull(paste0("var",1,"A")), x%>%pull(paste0("var",1,"B")))}
)%>%
map_df(tidy)%>% add_column(.before = 'estimate',df = list_dfs)
```

Now I get my desired output: (a table of t.tests for all dataframes for threshold 1)

```
# A tibble: 3 x 11
df    estimate estimate1 estimate2 statistic p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method   alternative
<chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>    <chr>      
1 df1     -0.371     0.534     0.906    -0.874   0.395      16.0   -1.27      0.529 Welch T~ two.sided  
2 df2      0.500     1.49      0.985     1.01    0.326      17.7   -0.542     1.54  Welch T~ two.sided  
3 df3     -0.363     1.13      1.49     -0.952   0.354      18.0   -1.16      0.438 Welch T~ two.sided
```

But now I want to run the t.test automatically for all 3 thresholds.
How I can put the thresholds into the map_function, so I get 3 new tables of the t.tests? (1 table for every threshold)

Comment: How do you set the threshold?

Comment: This is an example code. In my real data the thresholds are 1, 2 and 3 standard deviations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could loop through the thresholds within the function (in the first map) and do your tidying also inside it, then you could add other variables to indicate `df` and `threshold`

how about something like this:

```
list_dfs = c('df1','df2','df3')
thresholds = c(1, 2, 3)

map(list_dfs,
    function(df_name){
      x <- get(df_name)
      lapply(threshold, function(i){
        t.test(x %>%
                 pull(paste0("var",i,"A")), 
               x %>% 
                 pull(paste0("var",i,"B")))
      }) %>% 
        map_df(broom::tidy) %>% 
        add_column(.before = 'estimate',
                   df = df_name, 
                   threshold = thresholds)
    }) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .)
```